# Probability of $X-1 = Y$, where $X\sim Geo(p)$ and $Y\sim B(n,p)$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here's what I've got so far:

$$\begin{align}
P(X-1 = Y) &= \sum_{i=0}^nP(X-1 = Y=i)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^nP(X=i+1)\cdot P(Y=i)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n(1-p)^i p\cdot {n \choose i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
\end{align}$$

I tried combining the $(1-p)$ expressions and taking them out of the sum, but I'm still left with $\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}p^{i+1}$
I also tried to get a binomial sum, but to no avail

Is there any way to get rid of the sum notation in the final answer?

Comment: Apply the [binomial theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html).

Comment: Move a factor of $p$ outside too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align*}
P[ X - 1 = Y ]
&= \sum_{i=0}^n (1 - p)^i p \cdot {n \choose i} p^i (1 - p)^{n-i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \left\{ (1 - p)^n p \right\} {n \choose i} p^i \\
&= p (1 - p)^n \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} p^i \\
&= p (1 - p)^n (1 + p)^n , 
\end{align*}$

where the last equality follows from the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Hence the answer is $ p \left(1 - p^2 \right)^n $.